# How can I make both sides of this mesh bright in material mode?

Tags: texturing, objects

I have recently been started to model a fairy in blender but when I got to the wings I realized I have a problem... you see I don't want to give any width to the wing, so wanted to solve it with a two sided polygon like this:

[image]

But the problem is, the back side of the poly is always dark, and it makes the teyture darker too in material view. I want this model to be a game character, and I don't know how Unreal Engine will handle the backside culling.

Any alternative ideas how I should  solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Every face has a normal- a direction that shows where "outside" is. By this I mean that when multiple faces are joined into an object, it tells blender that the rest of the space is outside and inside the object is inside. Blender shows the inside portion darker so you know  where your normals are facing. Unreal engine will make backside normals invisible, so I would suggest a solidify modifier with a very thin thickness. The wing will remain very thin, but not have any normal issues.

Comment: Thank you, I will try.